# How to convert TermCollection to Tree object via CSOM

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, sharepoint-2013

I'm querying a SharePoint 2013 Term Store via the SharePoint Client Object Model in order to get a TermCollection.

I'd like to bind the results to a WPF TreeView control. Any idea how I can turn the TermCollection into something that the TreeView will understand?

```
    public static TermCollection GetTaxonomyTerms(string webUrl, string libraryTitle, string fieldTitle)
    {
        var context = new ClientContext(webUrl);
        var web = context.Web;
        var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryTitle);
        var fields = list.Fields;
        var field = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldTitle));
        context.Load(field);

        var termStores = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(context).TermStores;
        context.Load(termStores);

        context.ExecuteQuery(); // TODO: Can this ExecuteQuery be avoided by using a LoadQuery statement?
        var termStore = termStores.Where(t => t.Id == field.SspId).FirstOrDefault();
        var termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(field.TermSetId);
        var terms = termSet.GetAllTerms(); //TODO: Do we need a version that returns a paged set of terms? or queries the server again when a node is expanded?
        context.Load(terms);

        context.ExecuteQuery();
        return terms;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own code (please let me know if there's an easier way to do this).
My 'Term' object below is just a simple POCO with Name and Terms.

```
        var terms = SharePointHelper.GetTaxonomyTerms(webUrl, libraryTitle, fieldTitle);
        var term = terms.AsRootTreeViewTerm();
        ....
    }

    public static Term AsRootTreeViewTerm(this SP.TermCollection spTerms)
    {
        var root = new Term();
        foreach (SP.Term spTerm in spTerms)
        {
            List<string> names = spTerm.PathOfTerm.Split(';').ToList();
            var term = BuildTerm(root.Terms, names);
            if (!root.Terms.Contains(term))
                root.Terms.Add(term);
        }
        return root;
    }

    static Term BuildTerm(IList<Term> terms, List<string> names)
    {
        Term term = terms.Where(x => x.Name == names.First())
                         .DefaultIfEmpty(new Term() { Name = names.First() })
                         .First();
        names.Remove(names.First());
        if (names.Count > 0)
        {
            Term child = BuildTerm(term.Terms, names);
            if (!term.Terms.Contains(child))
                term.Terms.Add(child);
        }
        return term;
    }
```